# emacs lisp is there a way to improve this regular expression

Tags: regex, emacs

I would like this regular expression to put each term inside curly bracket. But if there is a term with an escape parameter concatenate this term with the next term

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "{ " "{"
(replace-regexp-in-string "}{" "} {" (replace-regexp-in-string     
"\\(.*?_.\\)" "{\\1}"  "\Delta y_t u_t")))
```

Desired output

```
y_t a_t ==> {y_t} {a_t}
\Delta y_t a_t ==> {\Delta y_t} {a_t}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
(replace-regexp-in-string
    "\\(\\(?:\\\\[^ \t]+[ \t]\\)?[^ \t]+\\)" "{\\1}" "z_t \\Delta y_t x_t")
```

using the same type of optional capture group as the previous answer.

Comment: it seems that you have nested group. How does this work in general? the ?: does not work in emacs as far as i know so it is not needed. But the main trouble is to get capture the backslash as well. Thanks for the try

Comment: @DJJ works for me, ?: means group is non-capture in emacs (like normal)

Comment: The string should be "\\Delta y_t x_t" though

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you might have to adjust the number of backslashes

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "}{" "} {" (replace-regexp-in-string     
"\(\(?:\\\w+ \)?\w+\)" "{\\1}"  "\Delta y_t u_t")))
```

Comment: thanks but I'm using elisp and I don't think the same regex apply.